# Effect of two-level variable on dependent variable

Tags: regression, multiple-regression

I have a linear regression model with several predictors. One of them is categorical with two levels. I used a t-test to determine whether the mean of the dependent variable differs between the two levels of this variable, and there is no difference. However, my variable selection methods are showing that this categorical variable should be kept in the model.

I'm wondering if someone could explain to me conceptually why a variable should be kept in the model if the levels provide no change in the dependent variable.

I can see that from observation to observation it's not just that categorical variable that's changing, it's all the predictors, so your observations aren't giving you the "everything else held constant" effect of that categorical variable -- I guess that's what the regression coefficient gives you. If anyone has a good way of explaining this I would really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A couple of things can explain this:

1. Your estimate is confounded by the absence of the other variables in the model.  The result would be a biased estimate, which if biased towards 0 could result in the failure to reject the null of a the test.

Its not hard to cook up an example of where this could happen.

```r
# Simulate a classic confounding example.
set.seed(0)
z = rnorm(100, 0, 1)
x = rbinom(100, 1, plogis(-2*z + 1))
y = x + 1 + z + rnorm(100, 0, 0.5)

# Equivalent to a t test
summary(lm(y~x))

Call:
lm(formula = y ~ x)

Residuals:
     Min       1Q   Median       3Q      Max 
-1.88514 -0.42185  0.01844  0.47140  2.23433 

Coefficients:
            Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)   1.8417     0.1409  13.074   <2e-16 ***
x            -0.2150     0.1761  -1.221    0.225    
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Residual standard error: 0.8452 on 98 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared:  0.01498,   Adjusted R-squared:  0.004928 
F-statistic:  1.49 on 1 and 98 DF,  p-value: 0.2251
```

Note that the effect of $x$ is in the wrong direction *and* we fail to reject the null.  More data makes the problem worse as we would precisely estimate the wrong effect.  Adding in $z$ to the model results in better estimates.

2. The estimate from the t test is not confounded but the residual variance is too large and results in a failure to reject the null.  Adding more variables into the model might explain away additional residual variance hence resulting in a rejection of the null.

Answer (score 0):

To prove what you are seeing, run a "univariate" regression with only the categorical predictor, and the Z-score (or t-test) for the regression coefficient and it's p-value for this univariate model should be close to the p-value of the t-test. (can't say identical, since software can use the Welch instead of t-test if variances are unequal, for which the degrees of freedom are adjusted, and depends on whether software assumes unequal or equal variances).

Next, add one or more of the other variables, and then perform the associated regression analyses -- and the coefficient and p-value of the categorical predictor will change in the presence of other values.  Why? It's because of shared correlation between the categorical variables and other predictors and the outcome dependent variable.

You can also run correlation between the dependent variable and all the predictors, and compare correlation coefficients between the categorical and dependent and the other variables and the dependent.  If the correlation between the other variable(s) and dependent is stronger than the categorical and the dependent, when you add all the predictors into the model, the other variables that are more correlated with the dependent will commonly have more significance, as they explain more variance in the dependent variable.